# How to only get the last 5 minutes tweets from Twitter API

Tags: api, twitter, twitter-api-v2

I am using the twitter V2 API, how would I be able to only get the last 5minutes tweets from the api, using `https://api.twitter.com/2/users/:id/tweets` [link](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-users-id-tweets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the `tweet.fields` parameters that it can take is `created_at`, which is passed in the form of an ISO-8601 timestamp. You can set that timestamp to be 5 minutes ago, to get the newest tweets